# How to group by and make sum from different sources in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` that contains the number of transactions between companies.

```
df  Receiver Payer   Amount  
0    0045    xx04     300 
1    5400    zz03     600
2    5400    0045     100
3    xx04    5400     400
```

For each companies I would like count `in` and `out` and distinguish it between companies with only numbers and companies with non-numeric values. I would like to return something like:

```
df1   ID     In_0    In_1    Out_0  Out_1
0    0045     0      300      100    0
1    5400    100     600       0    400
2    zz03     0       0       600    0
3    xx04    400      0       300    0
```

For now I just tried a simple `groupby`. For the total amount between each couple of companies, for instance such as

```
df.groupby(['Receiver', 'Payer'], as_index = False)['Amount'].sum()
```

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve the output?

Comment: Why is the out for ID 5400 in Out_1 and not Out_0?  And why is the In for ID 0045 in In_1 not in In_0?

Comment: @ScottBoston because ID 5400 pays only 400 to a nonnumeric company that has label 1. Same for the ID 0045 that receives from non-numeric company so label 1

Comment: @HarvIpan I am trying to do som simple `groupby` so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to a a little logic and reshaping your dataframe.

```
df_out = df.rename(columns={'Receiver':'IN','Payer':'OUT'})

df_out['IN_TYPE'] = df_out['OUT'].str.contains(r'\D').astype(int).astype(str)
df_out['OUT_TYPE'] = df_out['IN'].str.contains(r'\D').astype(int).astype(str)

df_out = df_out.melt(['df','Amount','IN_TYPE','OUT_TYPE'], value_name='ID')

df_out['Cols'] = df_out['variable']+'_'+np.where(df_out['variable']=='IN',df_out['IN_TYPE'],df_out['OUT_TYPE'])

df_out = df_out.groupby(['ID','Cols'])['Amount'].sum().unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
Cols    ID   IN_0   IN_1  OUT_0  OUT_1
0     0045    0.0  300.0  100.0    0.0
1     5400  100.0  600.0    0.0  400.0
2     xx04  400.0    0.0  300.0    0.0
3     zz03    0.0    0.0  600.0    0.0
```